# Simple Unit Test for Custom Controller

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have written plenty of unit tests for Triggers. But I am kind of stuck on how to write one out for a simple view controller.

Here is the custom controller for my VF Controller:

```
public with sharing class NotificationListController {

    private final Account account;

    public List<Account_Notification__c> notifications {get;set;}

    date d = system.today();

    public NotificationListController(){

        account = [SELECT Id FROM Account 
                   WHERE Id = :ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')];


        notifications = [SELECT Account__c, Related_Product__c, Description__c, Type__c, Expiration_Date__c, Active__c 
                         FROM Account_Notification__c 
                         WHERE Account__c = :account.Id 
                         AND Active__c    = true AND (Expiration_Date__c = null OR Expiration_Date__c > :d)  ];
    }

}
```

What needs to be asserted? Do I just create account notifications and check for their existence?

Thanks y'all.

Comment: Your first query is using the Account Id to get the Account Id. You could remove it and simply use the Account Id directly in the query for your Notifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case you *could* write methods for

1. Instantiate with the ID parameter of Existing ID and notification within expiration dates - Assert the value of Account and notifications are correct
2. Instantiate without the ID parameter - Assert the value of Account and notifications are correct and that no errors are present
3. Instantiate with the ID parameter of Existing ID and notification not within expiration dates - Assert the value of Account and notifications are correct
4. Instantiate with the ID parameter of a NON-existing Existing ID  - Assert the value of Account and notifications are correct and no errors
5. Instantiate with the ID parameter of Existing ID and no notification records existing - Assert the value of Account and notifications are correct

This may seem a bit overboard but if you want to do it right.....(And I could be missing some variations).

I can immediately see that with your current code:

2 and 4 will fail and throw an error

Comment: Overkill is good. Overboard is bad.

Comment: I try to instantiate the controller and pass an account created in the Unit Test but it tells me "Method does not exist or incorrect signature: [NotificationListController].account(Account)". Do you know the issue here?

Comment: @AllenMann ask a new question with your current code